# Highlight the table cell value based on textbox value outside the table

Tags: jquery, html-table, textbox

I want all the table cells values matching the textbox value to be highlighted when user types the text in the textbox....

```
<input type="text" id="txtsearch"/>  
<html>
<table id="table" style="height:350px;margin-left:1em;width:700px;">
    <!--this is my table header-->
    <tr style="display:table-row">
        <th class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/></th>
        <th class="Name">NAME</th>
        <th class="Score">SCORE</th>
        <th class="Email">EMAIL</th>
        <th class="Empty"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--tabledata-->
        <td ><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td >Vijay Prakash</td>
        <td >34</td>
        <td >vijay@gmail.com</td>
        <td ></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btnCalculate" value="Calculate"/>
<label>Average:</label>
<label id="lblAverage"></label>
<label>Max:</label>
<label id="lblMax"></label>
</form>
</html>   
</div>
```

Comment: where is the textbox? and which table cells? all or just the last row?

Comment: Its outside the table...all cells that are matching the value of the textbox...ie if the value in textbox is vijay..the table cells having name as "vijay prakash" and "vijay kumar" so on shud be highlighted

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that your textbox has 'textbox' ID and selected cells will use 'highlight' CSS class:

```
$('#textbox').on('change', function() {
  var textboxValue = $('#textbox').val();
  $('#table td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === textboxValue) {
      $(this).addClass('highlight');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    }
  });
});
```

See it in action on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqXpc/).

If you need it to make a partial match, replace `if` with the following:

```
if ($(this).text().indexOf(textboxValue) !== -1) {
```

If you need to match a string beginning from the start (not inside of another string, like example above), use this:

```
if ($(this).text().indexOf(textboxValue) === 0) {
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get any errors?  Did you create a `<textarea id="textbox"/>`?

Comment: My bad, I had couple of JS errors.  Now I checked and fixed it.

Comment: Wait, you need to match a **partial** string, not exact match?  The code I've written makes exact match.

Comment: The cell shud highlight when the user starts typing itself...ie if he types "v" it shud highlight all cells which start with letter v similarly "vi" and so on

Comment: Its highlighting the email column cells but I need the name column cells to be highlighted

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(function(){
console.log('');
$('#txtsearch').on('input', function() {
  var textboxValue = $('#txtsearch').val();
  if(textboxValue.length>0)
  {
  $('#table td').each(function() {
    var filter = textboxValue.toString().toUpperCase();
    if ($(this).html().toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      $(this).addClass('highlight');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    }
  });
  }
  else
  {
  $('#table td').removeClass('highlight');
  }
});
});
```

```css
.highlight
{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtsearch"/>  
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>SCORE</th>
        <th>EMAIL</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Vijay Prakash</td>
        <td >34</td>
        <td >vijay@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Neeraj Pathak</td>
        <td >100</td>
        <td >npathak56@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```